# Account management using json

Tags: python, json, authentication, passwords, account

Hi. I am trying to make a program that is able to create users and then log them in. Once you're logged in you can change your password. What I can't seem to figure out is how to get it to change your password after you logged in, using only your old password. I can get it to work by inputting your account name, but that's not the point.
Do any of you have any idea of how to fix this problem, I am open to suggestions :)

```
import json

with open("login_data.txt", "r") as login_file:
    try:
        users = json.load(login_file)
    except:
        users = {}

status = ""

def Display_Menu():

    status = input("Are you a registered user? (y/n)? Press q to quit: ")
    if status == "y":
        Old_User()
    elif status == "n":
        New_User()
    elif status == "passwd":
        Change_Passwd()
    elif status == "q":
        skriva = open("login_data.txt", "w")
        json.dump(users, skriva)
    return status

def New_User():

    Create_Login =input("Create login name: ")
    if Create_Login in users:
        print ("Login name already exist!")
    else:
        Create_Password =input("Create password: ")
        users[Create_Login] = Create_Password
        print("New User created!")

def Old_User():

    login =input("Enter login name: ")
    Password =input("Enter password: ")

    if login in users and users[login] == Password:

        print("Login successful!")
        print(users[login])

        status = input("Wanna quit, change pass, och logout?")       
        if status == "passwd":
            Change_Passwd()
        elif status == "logout":
            Display_Menu()
        elif status == "q":
            skriva = open("login_data.txt", "w")
            json.dump(users, skriva)
        return status

    else:
        print("User doesn't exist or wrong password!")

def Change_Passwd():

    oldpass =input("Old password: ")

    if oldpass in users:
        Create_Password =input("New password: ")
        users[oldpass] = Create_Password

        if Create_Password == input("Confirm password: "):
            print("Password changed!")
        else:
            print("User authorization failure")
            users[create_Login] = oldpass
    else:
        print ("No password match!")


while status != "q":            
    status = Display_Menu()
```

## A example of a account file " { "halo": "molly"} "

Answer (score 0):

The minimal change would be to save the currently logged in user to a global variable in Old_User(). Then, when Change_Passwd is called, you can go back to that variable to determine which user you're dealing with. Here's the changes you'd make to Old_User. I'll leave the changes to Change_Passwd up to you to implement.

```
current_user = None # Declare global variable for saving logged in user
def Old_User():
    global current_user  # Indicate that we're going to modify the global variable in the local scope

    login =input("Enter login name: ")
    Password =input("Enter password: ")

    if login in users and users[login] == Password:

        print("Login successful!")
        print(users[login])
        current_user = login  # Save the logged in user.
        ...
```

I should also add that you'd be better served using classes for this. Trying to maintain state (like who the current user is) using global variables is not very scalable and can get confusing pretty quickly. Having classes representing users and active sessions would make things easier.